# join another table without a join for limit at one

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT op.id,op.nome,op.cognome,op.ore_giornaliere,
(select tp.* from turni_preconf as tp where tp.tot_ore =  op.ore_giornaliere limit 5,1)             
FROM operatori as op
```

return me an error :

## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

i need o select an other table without join

Thank you

Comment: What are your desired results?  And why can't you use `JOIN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery can return only one column and one row (i.e. one value) when used as a column expression. If you need more than one column from the table in the subquery, you will need more than one subquery. E.g.:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b
(SELECT TOP 1 t2.a FROM t2 WHERE something = true) as c,
(SELECT TOP 1 t2.b FROM t2 WHERE something = true) as d
FROM t1
```

Here is some good reading on subqueries: [Subquery Fundamentals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: OK thank you, but if you show a pratical example, with my parameters, is better for me...